# Отрисовка спрайта при нажатии кнопки мыши

Tags: c++, sfml

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии правой кнопки мыши рисовался спрайт с текстуры

```cpp
sf::Vector2i pixelPos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(app); 
sf::Vector2f pos = app.mapPixelToCoords(pixelPos);

while (app.pollEvent(event))
    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Right))
            {
                rightMouse = true;
                sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(186, 0, 216, 30)); 
            }
```

Пытался сделать так, но не выходит.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
if (rightMouse) {
    app.draw(sprite);
}
```

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение к вопросу? )

Comment: @Suvitruf Это ответ.